# making it imposible to create new files inside folder

Tags: linux

I am trying to prevent the creation of file posibility inside a linux folder, so that it will be impossible to create new files inside this specific folder.
I have tried changing the mode to r only with:

> chmod 0544 -R

but unfortunately this doesnt help.

how can I disable the creation of new files?

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the actual directory (not "folder") on which you want to do that?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch actually i have a system with many processes and i want to see which process alters the file.

Comment: Then you want `lsof` or perhaps using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above command will work - for all users expect of(!) the `root` user.

---

As @BasileStarynkevitch suggested, Having that you are using an ext filesystem (or any other filesystem which supports the following attribute), you can use the `chattr` program to restrict even the `root` user from creating files in that directory by accident. (By accident, because `root` is of course free to use `chattr` again to reset the attribute).

```
sudo chattr +i /path/to/folder
```

`i` means immutable. Use `+i` to set the attribute and `-i` to reset the attribute. Note that only the `root` user can set or reset this attribute.

Comment: is there any way to prevent to root from creating files?

Comment: There might be circumvented ways (e.g. `chattr`) but root will always be able to change these restrictions.